# Diophantine Equations... $255x + 345y = 60$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to know how to find the general solution by integers to any equation (or identify when there is no such integer solution). The example in my mock exam is $255x + 345y = 60$. I think you need the integers $u, v$ such that $255u + 345v = \gcd(255,345) = 15$ as I was asked that in the previous question. ($u = -4$, $v = 3$).

Finding the $u$ and $v$ is easy enough but I don't know how to derive the general solution using them. I assume that once I know the method I will be able to ascertain on sight whether an equation has integer solutions, if not how would I do that?

Comment: Just use the fact that $60=15\cdot4=(255u+345v)\cdot4=255\cdot4u+345\cdot4v$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $15$ divides $60$, it's quite easy to get from the equation you know to what you want.

You have
$$
-4\cdot 255+3\cdot 345=15
$$
if you multiply by $4$, you get
$$
4(-4\cdot 255+3\cdot 345)=60\\
-16\cdot 255+12\cdot 345=60
$$
so $x=-16$  and $y=12$ is the solution you want.

Comment: I need to find the general solution. How would I do that? How would I do that generally? Well, I know the general solution as this is from a mock exam but of course I need to be able to answer these myself.